# changing CPU clock speed during program exuction

Tags: embedded, clock

Main applicataion on our micro (RH850) were developed to work with clock speed X Mhz. Bootloader which is alwyas executed first, initializes clock speed to X/3 MHz. We cant change speed in bootloader to X Mhz, due to some limiations within libaraires which are used by the bootloader.

Is there any possiblity to reinitialize clock speed in bootloader from X/3 Mhz to X MHz, lets say, just before bootloader does jump to application?

What is the common practice of such a clock handling embedded systems? Is there any general way, or is this rather micro specific?

regards
J.

Comment: changing clock speeds/sources on the fly are very specific to the logic design, there is no universal answer to this question other than you have to dig into the specific details for that part.  it may just always work or it may require that you are running from ram and not flash or vice versa or it might not work at all for some parts.

Comment: this is a question for the documentation for the part or the chip vendor, what did they say when you asked them?

Comment: Probably, yes.  Look at the startup code - typically in a chip with a PLL you start with an unmultiplied clock, startup the PLL wait for it to stabilize and then switch to it.  Switching from one PLL rate to another could require going back to the source clock during the change.  But this question is too broad to be a fit here - your resource needs to be the chip programmer's manual and any vendor provided initialization code.

Answer (score 0):

So it worked in following way:

1. switch back to main oscillator
2. disable PLLs
3. reconfigure PLLs
4. enable PLLs
5. change CPU source to PLL you just reconfigured